# CPU running at 100% all the time in the Ubuntu VM

Tags: performance, cpu

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu and am unsure why the core is at 100% constantly, there is a noticeable effect on performance. Did anyone get any ideas?

[image: pic of the top and other system processes info]

HOST CPU usage with VM ON
[image: HOST CPU usage with VM ON]

HOST CPU usage with VM OFF
[image: HOST CPU usage with VM OFF]

Comment: The CPU usage indicated inside a VM is not always 100% helpful particular when the host is on a CPU with power saving features - what is the CPU usage on the host?

Comment: I added 2 pics of 60 seconds into the VM being ON and OFF.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue sometime back i had disable nested paging and it worked like a charm

Can you check if Nested Paging is Disabled? if not please shut the VM down and disable Nested Paging under System :) see below

[image]

Start the VM back and let us know if that helped.

Waiting for your reply

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem to have changed anything. still at 100%

Comment: are you running other VM or just one Ubuntu VM , if you are running other VM , what is the CPU on those ?  this is clarify if that image issue or something else ?

Comment: Just the one VM